# Basic JavaScript pop up boxes

Tags: javascript, popup

Can anyone see where I am doing wrong? I'd like each function to run after each other. Is this even possible the way I am doing it? Thanks

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Java Script Test</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function alertA() {
      var name = prompt("What's your first name");
      if (name.length < 13) {
        alert("Hi Paul")
      } else {
        alert("Don't lie, your name is Paul");
      }
    }

    function redirect() {
      var r = confirm("Do you think Lee has learned JavaScript? If yes click    OK")
      if (r == true) {
        window.location = 'http://www.youtube.com';
      } else {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Click me!" onClick="alertA()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run after each other"?

Comment: Change `onClick="alertA()"` to `onClick="alertA();redirect()"`. This will run the functions one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `redirect()` at the end of `function alertA(){...}`

```
function alertA() {
    var name = prompt("What's your first name");
    if (name.length < 13) {
        alert("Hi Paul")
    } else {
        alert("Don't lie, your name is Paul");
    }
    redirect() // <<<<<<<----- calling next function
}

function redirect() {
    var r = confirm("Do you think Lee has learned JavaScript? If yes click    OK")
    if (r == true) {
        window.location = 'http://www.youtube.com';
    } else {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
}
```

You could also merge both functions into a single one:

```
function alertA() {
    var name = prompt("What's your first name");
    if (name.length < 13) {
        alert("Hi Paul")
    } else {
        alert("Don't lie, your name is Paul");
    }

    var r = confirm("Do you think Lee has learned JavaScript? If yes click    OK")
    if (r == true) {
        window.location = 'http://www.youtube.com';
    } else {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
}
```

Comment: check out the @user2314737 answer too, and make sure to accept the one you seem fittest :)